# How to calculate used memory of 'free' command

Tags: memory-usage, free

How to calculate used memory?
In below case, 15784520(RSS memory of 'top' command) + ? = 16031516(used memory of 'free' command)

```
root@host:~# free -w
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:       82376116    16031516    30084440       16780        2328    36257832    65487292
Swap:             0           0           0

root@host:~#  ps aux | awk '{sum +=$5}END{print sum}'
111284060

root@host:~#  ps aux | awk '{sum +=$6}END{print sum}'
15784520

root@host:~#  cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       82376116 kB
MemFree:        30077632 kB
MemAvailable:   65480784 kB
Buffers:            2328 kB
Cached:         30545640 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         24199852 kB
Inactive:       19097572 kB
Active(anon):   12741724 kB
Inactive(anon):     7588 kB
Active(file):   11458128 kB
Inactive(file): 19089984 kB
Unevictable:         160 kB
Mlocked:             160 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               312 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      12741616 kB
Mapped:          1301004 kB
Shmem:             16780 kB
KReclaimable:    5712492 kB
Slab:            7411268 kB
SReclaimable:    5712492 kB
SUnreclaim:      1698776 kB
KernelStack:       40496 kB
PageTables:        51424 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    41188056 kB
Committed_AS:   26394284 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      328328 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:           106656 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:      4096 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:     3090304 kB
DirectMap2M:    73455616 kB
DirectMap1G:     9437184 kB
```

Comment: Nice use of `awk` to sum up columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15.7 GB is used by processes, and 16.0 GB used in total.

This means that probably around 300 MB is used by the kernel "behind-the-scenes", just by itself or for filesystem operations.

This is not in any way unnatural, and just the way Ubuntu/Linux (or any other OS for that matter) works.

Also see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439869/high-memory-usage-that-cannot-be-traced-to-a-service-or-application).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.