# How can I correctly calculate the sum of memory used by all processes?

Tags: process, memory-usage, ps

There recently was a couple of questions asking why Ubuntu is seemingly using more memory than accounted for by processes/services - [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439869/high-memory-usage-that-cannot-be-traced-to-a-service-or-application/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444242/how-to-caluculate-used-memory-of-free-command/).

However, I have the exact opposite situation. On my server, the memory used by all processes seems to be higher than the total memory used. Let me provide the evidence.

Output of `free -m`:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           64277       15014       34424          31       14837       48530
Swap:           8191           0        8191
```

Output of `arcstat`:

```
    time  read  miss  miss%  dmis  dm%  pmis  pm%  mmis  mm%  size     c  avail
09:38:57     0     0      0     0    0     0    0     0    0  9.8G  9.8G    41G
```

Output of `ps aux | awk '{sum +=$6}END{print sum}'`:

```
6351512
```

So what this means for me is:

`free -m` reports a total of 15.0 GB memory used (shared memory is neglible). Subtract from this 9.8 GB reported by `arcstat` for ZFS ARC Cache. The remaining result is around 5.2 GB of "real" used memory. But the sum of column 6 in `ps aux` (RSS - resident set size) totals to 6.35 GB. This would mean that reported memory used by all processes is 1.15 GB higher than it actually is shown by `free -m`.

I wonder if there is a way I can correctly calculate the memory used by all processes, so it matches the used memory (after ZFS cache and shared ramdisks are subtracted)?

Comment: Not entirely sure on how accounting is done with forked processes, but if say, something like Firefox had a lot of forked process, each would have roughly similar RSS, but the actual memory used due to CoW would be much lower because they won't get their own copy of each part of memory until it's modified. Just a guess, quite likely I'm wrong on how CoW for forking and memory usage reporting works here.

Comment: Yeah I'll have to look a little more into the `ps` list. Also, it seems `smem` reports the correct amount, so maybe I'll do a comparison and see if I can find where they differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as many are probably aware, the memory statistics reported by `ps` (and the metric RSS itself) aren't entirely accurate because of shared memory pages.

There is another tool called `smem`, which correctly reports the proportionate set size for each process - that is each process' memory consumption where the shared memory is divided in a sane way between processes.

From [`man smem`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/smem.8.html):

> ```
> smem reports physical memory usage, taking shared memory pages into account.
> Unshared memory is reported as the USS (Unique Set Size). Shared memory is 
> divided evenly among the processes sharing that memory. The unshared memory
> (USS) plus a process's proportion of shared memory is reported as the PSS 
> (Proportional Set Size). The USS and PSS only include physical memory usage. 
> They do not include memory that has been swapped out to disk.
> ```

However, there are a few handy tricks for installing and configuring `smem` to easily report actual used memory by all processes.

###### Installing and configuring `smem`

First, if you want to install `smem`, you need to have the Universe repository enabled. Make sure this line is uncommented in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (for Ubuntu 22.04):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
```

When you're normally trying to install `smem`, it wants to install a ton of dependencies (a little over 100 packages), because it has a recommended dependency on `python3-matplotlib` for generating graphical charts.

Since I don't need this (and anybody with a server probably don't need it either), it's possible to only install the base package with this command:

```
sudo apt install smem python3-matplotlib-
```

Notice the dash after `python3-matplotlib` - this indicates that this packages should *not* be installed. Another option is to use:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends smem
```

This has the same result, which will only install the `smem` package.

The final trick is to fix the columns, so you can correctly use `awk`, or export the metrics in a way where you can trust the columns. To do this, we need to move the `command` column to the rightmost place, since the `command` field can include additional spaces we can't control.

To fix the column layout and size, `smem` should be run with these options:

```
smem -ac "user pid swap maps vss uss pss rss command"
```

In addition, to include all processes, it has to be run as `sudo`. I've defined the following alias for `smem`:

```
alias smem='sudo smem -ac "user pid swap maps vss uss pss rss command"'
```

So in the following, when I type the command `smem`, it does in fact run the command with the above options.

###### Comparing `smem` and `ps` metrics

Now we can correctly compare the metrics of `ps aux` and `smem`. I was expecting a "real" used memory of 5.2 GB, but `ps aux` reported 6.35 GB used. Below are the results from `smem`.

Count of RSS from `smem`:

```
$ smem | awk '{sum +=$8}END{print sum}'
6464644
```

Count of PSS from `smem`:

```
$ smem | awk '{sum +=$7}END{print sum}'
5281005
```

Now it's clear that the RSS reported is roughly similar (a little higher from `smem`). But it's also clear that the proportionate set size (PSS) more correctly matches the expected memory usage among processes - 5.2 GB.

So to correctly measure total process memory usage, the PSS metric from `smem` seems to give the most meaningful result.